# Read a field in MYSQL Gravity Forms in Worpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Is possible read a field in MYSQL using Gravity Forms in Wordpress? 
I need to show in a combo a field from MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Harder: Use [dynamic population](https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/#hooks) and [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable) to query for your value.

   ```
   function my_populate_func( $value ) {
       global $wpdb;
       return $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT whatever FROM wp_my_table WHERE something = else' );
   }
   ```
2. Easier: Use [Gravity Forms Populate Anything](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/) to query and populate directly from the field settings (no code).

   [image: Populate Anything Field Settings]